# React JS npm run failing

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and have just created an app, However "npm run" command is not working, I have checked other answers but found that my code didn't throw any error after the run command, Below the message in command prompt.
[image]

I have checked the issues raised in github, However it did not help.
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1767

Below is the package.json file.

```html
{
  "name": "my-app1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The app was supposed to run on the local port.

Comment: You need to tell it *what* to run, `npm run` isn't a complete command on its own. That's why it's listing the things you *can* run. Did you mean `npm [run[-script]] start`, for example?

Comment: Downgraded the node js version to 10 instead of the latest version, it worked, Despite using the "npm react-script start" it didn't work, still threw event.js  error.

Answer (score 0):

you should type `npm run start`
keep in mind that `npm start` also works correctly. but only in the case of using **start** script and won't work with other scripts.

Comment: Also works with test - you can see this in the logs the OP shows, they're the ones described as "lifecycle scripts". See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts, they're listed at the top.